# Reformat JSON in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Is there a utility that will help me reformat JSON structure in Rails, JS or Ruby?

I'm making a call to a legacy db with raw sql.
sql_result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
render json: sql_result, root:false

Data returns fine but I need to reformat this JSON output...
["MyBiz, LLC",
   "55 Main St","San Francisco","CA","94103",
   "3/06/2007","12/31/2007"]

To look like this... 
{
    "Company":"MyBiz, LLC",
    "Address":"55 Main St",
    "City":"San Francisco",
    "State":"CA",
    "ZipCode":"94103",
    "Start":"03/06/2007",
    "End":"12/31/2007"
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field names were lost. Try something like:

```
 keys = ["Company", "Address", "City", "State", "ZipCode", "Start", "End"]
 ["MyBiz, LLC", "55 Main St","San Francisco","CA","94103", "3/06/2007","12/31/2007"].
   each_with_index.map { |v, i| { keys[i] => v } }.reduce(:merge).to_json

 #  => "{\"Company\":\"MyBiz, LLC\",\"Address\":\"55 Main St\",\"City\":\"San Francisco\",\"State\":\"CA\",\"ZipCode\":\"94103\",\"Start\":\"3/06/2007\",\"End\":\"12/31/2007\"}"
```

Comment: This is beautiful. The code I posted wasn't exactly the right format but you answered correctly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
 keys = ["Company", "Address", "City", "State", "ZipCode", "Start", "End"]
 Hash[*keys.zip(sql_result).flatten]
```